# How to reduce the lines of code with multi variable equations?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, contour, equation

I am trying to reduce lines of code because I realized that I am repeating the same equations every time. I am programming a contour map and putting several sources of intensity into it. Until now I put 3 sources, but in the future I want to put more, and that will increase the lines a lot. So I want to see if it is possible to reduce the lines of "source positions" and "Intensity equations". As you can see the last equation is a logaritmic summation of z1, z2 and z3, is it possible to reduce that, any idea?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def run():
    # mesh
    N = 100
    x = np.linspace(-N, N)
    y = np.linspace(-N, N)
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)


    # sources coordinates
    p1 = [-5,-1]
    p2 = [6 , 0]
    p3 = [-10 , -8]


    # sources postions

    R1 = np.sqrt((((p1[0]-X)**2)+((p1[1]-Y)**2)))
    R2 = np.sqrt((((p2[0]-X)**2)+((p2[1]-Y)**2)))
    R3 = np.sqrt((((p3[0]-X)**2)+((p3[1]-Y)**2)))

    # # Intensity Equation

    z1 = np.round(10 * np.log10((((((R1/(1000**(1/3)))**-1.45) * 516)/(20**(-3)))**2)),0)
    z2 = np.round(10 * np.log10((((((R2/(1000**(1/3)))**-1.45) * 516)/(20**(-3)))**2)),0)
    z3 = np.round(10 * np.log10((((((R3/(4000**(1/3)))**-1.45) * 516)/(20**(-3)))**2)),0) 

    z_total = 10*np.log10((10**(z1/10))+(10**(z2/10)+(10**(z3/10))))

    # # Ploting

    Z = np.array(z_total).reshape(len(y),len(x))
    cs = plt.contourf(X,Y,Z,10)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()

if __name__ =='__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over certain parts in a loop.

I tried to keep the same format overall and just rearranged the code to show how you might do it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def run():
    # mesh
    N = 100
    x = np.linspace(-N, N)
    y = np.linspace(-N, N)
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

    # sources coordinates
    p = [
        [-5,-1],
        [6 , 0],
        [-10 , -8],
    ]

    # sources postions + intensity Equation
    z_log = 0
    for px, py in p:
        r = np.sqrt((((px-X)**2)+((py-Y)**2)))
        z = np.round(10 * np.log10((((((r/(1000**(1/3)))**-1.45) * 516)/(20**(-3)))**2)),0)
        z_log += 10**(z/10)
    z_total = 10*np.log10(z_log)

    # # Ploting
    Z = np.array(z_total).reshape(len(y),len(x))
    cs = plt.contourf(X,Y,Z,10)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()

if __name__ =='__main__':
    run()
```

A recommendation I'd have is spread out operators (`x + y * 2` is preferred over `x+y*2`), give your variables descriptive names (eg. `coordinates` and not `p`), and split your calculations into more parts. There are so many brackets in `z` for example that I'd hate to try and debug if something was not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try making smaller, more bitesize functions outside of the `run()` method. Name them clearly to what they do and accomplish (helps with readability) Here's an example of how to make this small function cleaner.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# declare 'mesh' outside of run to get from other functions
N = 100
x = np.linspace(-N, N)
y = np.linspace(-N, N)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

def run():
   
    # sources postions
    R1 = getSourcePosition([-5,-1])
    R2 = getSourcePosition([6 , 0])
    R3 = getSourcePosition([-10 , -8])

    ...

def getSourcePosition(p1):
    # X,Y available from above declaration
    return np.sqrt((((p1[0]-X)**2)+((p1[1]-Y)**2)))

if __name__ =='__main__':
    run()
```

If this was a larger function with classes, packages, and more moving parts I wouldn't recommend the global variables but it looks like you are just trying to run what looks like a simple script